# Creating a Custom Keyboard in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

What is best way to create a custom keyboard for my Application in windows phone7? If I do So will it accepted in Market?And how to disable Windows phone 7 default keypad?

Answer (score 1):

I used this as a start point when i wrote Slydr (Sliding keyboard app) http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx

**just so you know, you cannot replace system keyboard.**